# SQL: How to display data with row values as column names and then count number of times ID per row value?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my database and fiddle setup:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
    NAME varchar(20),
    PRODUCT_ID int(3)
);

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
    NAME varchar(20),
    PAYMENT_ID int(4)
);

INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
VALUES
("Apple", 1), 
("Banana", 2), 
("Watermelon", 3),
("Bread", 4), 
("Milk", 5), 
("Cake", 6), 
("Candy", 7), 
("Butter", 8), 
("Carrot", 9),
("Tomato", 10);


INSERT INTO PAYMENT (NAME, PAYMENT_ID)
VALUES
("Banana", 85),
("Apple", 94),
("Banana", 94),
("Candy", 85),
("Banana", 105);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5jsGYfWZ6pnzgf62Z5FA8L/0

I'm thinking I have to do some Count(CASE statement within here).

I saw something about pivots, but not sure about that?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right, that is a possibility

I use IF when there is only one option.

```
SELECT 
    p.NAME
    ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 85,1,0)) '85'
    ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 94,1,0)) '94'
    ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 105,1,0)) '105'
FROM PRODUCTS p LEFT JOIN PAYMENT pa ON p.NAME = pa.NAME
GROUP BY p.NAME;
```

There Reference between the two tables should be the id and not the name, the name maybe unique, but numbers need less space than text.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS (
>     NAME varchar(20),
>     PRODUCT_ID int(3)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
>     NAME varchar(20),
>     PAYMENT_ID int(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (NAME, PRODUCT_ID)
> VALUES
> ("Apple", 1), 
> ("Banana", 2), 
> ("Watermelon", 3),
> ("Bread", 4), 
> ("Milk", 5), 
> ("Cake", 6), 
> ("Candy", 7), 
> ("Butter", 8), 
> ("Carrot", 9),
> ("Tomato", 10);
>
>
> INSERT INTO PAYMENT (NAME, PAYMENT_ID)
> VALUES
> ("Banana", 85),
> ("Apple", 94),
> ("Banana", 94),
> ("Candy", 85),
> ("Banana", 105);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     p.NAME
>     ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 85,1,0)) '85'
>     ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 94,1,0)) '94'
>     ,SUM(IF(PAYMENT_ID = 105,1,0)) '105'
> FROM PRODUCTS p LEFT JOIN PAYMENT pa ON p.NAME = pa.NAME
> GROUP BY p.NAME;
> ```
>
> ```
> NAME       | 85 | 94 | 105
> :--------- | -: | -: | --:
> Apple      |  0 |  1 |   0
> Banana     |  1 |  1 |   1
> Bread      |  0 |  0 |   0
> Butter     |  0 |  0 |   0
> Cake       |  0 |  0 |   0
> Candy      |  1 |  0 |   0
> Carrot     |  0 |  0 |   0
> Milk       |  0 |  0 |   0
> Tomato     |  0 |  0 |   0
> Watermelon |  0 |  0 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=06ed9e5d5913e1e875a4d08992344b8e)*

Comment: Hi nbk, thanks, I found an example here and got basically the same solution as you through modifying it somewhat: https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/sql-how-to-select-field-values-and-return-them-as-column-names-in-result/111696/3

One last question I have.....does the then 1 hard-code it as 1? What if Banana has 2 entries under 85?

Comment: nvm, answered it by testing out the code myself, haha thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a convenient shortcut.  I recommend:

```
SELECT p.NAME,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 85) as payment_85,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 94) as payment_94,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 105) as payment_105
FROM PRODUCTS p LEFT JOIN
     PAYMENT pa
     ON p.NAME = pa.NAME
GROUP BY p.NAME;
```

Of course, if you don't care about products with no payments, you only need one table:

```
SELECT pa.NAME,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 85) as payment_85,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 94) as payment_94,
       SUM(pa.PAYMENT_ID = 105) as payment_105
FROM PAYMENT pa
GROUP BY pa.NAME;
```